# Django email, name - not null, not empty, without default

Tags: django

I'm trying to rewrite conceptual model of my database to django `models.py`. I want a user to have `name`, `surname` and `email`. None of those should be null, none of those should be blank. In `postgres` I'd just be able to add constraints to those fields, but django requires me to specify some default value for those fields. I don't really want to specify none of those default values, because all of them are user specific and should be got from the user.
How should I reformulate my model defition?

```
class users(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

EDIT:
Could I just rewrite the `save` method for this class to allow only valid addresses and valid names/surnames? Then I could possibly allow them both to be blank and only change, if they are not while inserting them with `save()`. Is this a good idea?

EDIT2: the problem with not being able to perform a migration is solved, but I'd still want to know if adding constraints to save method is a good idea.

Comment: You aren't required to specify a default value if you don't want to, and blank=False is assumed, so you don't actually need to specify it. Not setting a field to blank=True just means that just means that you'll provide those values for those fields when you create the object itself. Where are you seeing Django tell you that you must specify a default value?

Comment: While trying to make a migration django says:  
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'email' to users without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something
g rows).  
Please select a fix:  
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)  
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Ah I see. That error happens because some objects in your database do not have names/surnames set. Django tries to help with the migration by offering to transition over objects that already exist. If you're okay with losing the data on these objects, delete them and the error will go away. If you'd prefer to keep them, choose option 1 and give them a default value for now temporarily. Future models will not have those values set: they'll cause an error if you try to make one without a name and surname (which is what you want)

Comment: I don't have any data saved in my database, that would concern this part of the app.

Comment: The problem is I misunderstood migrations. Since I've had no data in that database, only some messy previous migrations I just removed all the migrations. The second part of the question still holds though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `clean()` method to your model where you validate all the fields you need to validate and raise `ValidationError` if something is wrong.

```
class users(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if not is_valid_surname(self.surname):
            raise ValidationError({'surname': _('Invalid surname.')})
        ...
```

The [docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).